# Run function when PDO is used to record sql queries?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this code:

```
<?php    
if(!$sql->execute()) {
    error($sql->errorinfo());
} else {
    $sql_queries[] = logQueries($sql, $settings['logQueries']);
}

function logQueries ($sql, $setting) {
    if($setting == 1) {
        ob_start();
        $sql->debugDumpParams(); 
        $query = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    return $query;
}
?>
```

BUT, this means adjusting the code all over the application. How can I extend the PDO class so that the logQueries is called on every execute or query?

Comment: what are you going to do with this array, $sql_queries?

Comment: just display it foreach($_SESSION['sql_queries'] AS $key => $value) {
            echo $key.' => '.$value.'<br><br>';
        }